# Ogden’s lemma on CFG

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to understand Ogden's lemma, and I know there are 4 cases, but in the next example I can only find 3:

Assume A = {$0^n1^m0^k$ | k = $max${n, m}} is CF:

Choose z = $0^k1^k0^k ∈ A$, z = xuvwy (with uw containing at least one 1):

1. u or w contains one 1 and one 0, so  $xu^2vw^2y ∉ A$
2. if w = ε, then u = $1^n$ so z = $xu^2vy$ = $0^k1^{k+n}0^k ∉ A$
3. if u = ε, then w = $1^n$ so z = $xvw^2y$ = $0^k1^{k+n}0^k ∉ A$

Am I doing this right? And what is the fourth case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did someone tell you there must be four cases? Ogden's lemma certainly doesn't require that.

Comment: Yes my teacher told me so. But otherwise, do the three cases I'm explaining are enough to prove it isn't CF?

Comment: You haven't considered the case where $w$ and $u$ are both nonempty. Also, it would help if you explicitly stated that you choose to mark the 1s as distinguished.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Does z = $xu^2vw^2y$ when u and w both nonempty?